# Scrapy-Selenium: Chrome Driver does not load page

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, selenium-chromedriver, scrapy-selenium

I have two projects, one with Selenium and one using Scrapy-Selenium, which fits into a Scrapy spider program format but uses Selenium for automation.

I can get the Chromedriver to load the page I want for the basic Selenium program, but something about the second project (with Scrapy) prevents it from loading the URL. Instead it's stuck at showing **data:,** in the URL bar.

First project (works fine):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver")
driver.get("https://ricemedia.co")
```

Second project (doesn't load page):

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from selenium import webdriver
import time

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'rice'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield SeleniumRequest(
            url="https://ricemedia.co",
            wait_time=3,
            callback=self.parse
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver")
        driver.maximize_window()
        time.sleep(20)
```

I have browsed StackOverflow and Google, and the two most common reasons are outdated Chrome Drivers and missing http in the URL. Neither is the case for me. The path to chromedriver seems alright too (these two projects are in the same folder, along with the same chromedriver). Since one works and the other doesn't, it should have something to do with my Scrapy-Selenium spider.

I should add that I have installed Scrapy, Selenium and Scrapy-Selenium locally in my virtual environment with pip, and I doubt it's an installation issue.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: make sure it's ./chromedriver.exe

Comment: It is chromedriver because the file itself is named chromedriver directly from the download (I'm on mac). And it works for the first one so I don't think it's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another method to install chrome driver:
First of all install  Webdriver manager using following  `pip install webdriver-manager` or use maven dep to get it

Then code:

```
# selenium 3
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```